# Αdd variables from one NetCDF file as attributes to another NetCDF file

Tags: latitude-longitude, netcdf

I have a netCDF in a rotated lat lon grid (file-a). I also have another file which contains the right lats and lons as two different variables (file-b). What I need to do is import the lats and lons from file-b to my variable in file-a as attributes. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't do it as NetCDF attributes, (I'm not sure what that would mean) but since they are different variables, you could use the NetCDF Operator tool `ncks` to extract the new variables from file_b and paste them onto the file_a:

```
ncks -A -v latnew,lonnew file_b.nc file_a.nc
```